# JQuery div.show() is resizing my fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a hide div that when I click on a checkbox, that div shows. My problem is that when the div shows the height of input fields are too small.

My div:

```
    <div id="payment" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2">Credit Card</label>
        <div class="col-lg-2" id="sq-card-number"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2">CVV</label>
        <div class="col-lg-1" id="sq-cvv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2">Expiration Date</label>
        <div class="col-lg-1" id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-offset-2">Postal Code</label>
        <div class="col-lg-1" id="sq-postal-code"></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-1">
            <button id="applyApplication" name="applyApplication" type="button" onClick="submitApplication();" class="btn btn-success center-block" disabled>Submit Application</button>
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the input fields:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .sq-input {
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 1px;
    }
    .sq-input--focus {
      outline-width: 5px;
      outline-color: #70ACE9;
      outline-offset: -1px;
      outline-style: auto;
    }
    .sq-input--error {
      outline-width: 5px;
      outline-color: #FF9393;
      outline-offset: 0px;
      outline-style: auto;
    }
</style>
```

And I control to display that div or not by JQuery:

```
    $('#agree').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#payment").show();
        $("#payment").scrollTop($("#payment").prop("scrollHeight"));
    } else{
        $("#payment").hide();
    }
});
```

Here is the div that there is my checkbox:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-2">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="agree" name="agree" value="agree" /> Agree with the terms and conditions
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Everything is working fine. When my checkbox is checked it display the div, but the input fields are with height very small. BTW, if I open the firebug, the input height adjust automatically. Does anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: you need to show us the div that is clickable, currently you have a div that is display none

Comment: I edited my post. Now it has the div. I am sorry

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read somewhere (sorry can't find the post) that the height of DOM objects is calculated at page load in some browsers. If your div starts out hidden and then is shown through Javascript I don't think the height recalculation is getting triggered. Just to see if that is the problem, remove the `display none` from your div and then add it using Javascript after the document is ready.

Comment: It that solves the problem I have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix the height in your css :

```
.sq-input {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 1px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Here is a Fiddle exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/qboena51/